# Adding label to last point matplotlib line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I have a plot with 2 subplots, where each line dynamically updates every time new data arrives. Each time the function is called, the axis is cleared and then redrawn with the new data. The

How would I go about adding data labels to the last point on all 4 lines? I have looked into suggestions and tutorials on using annotate but the syntax is a bit over my head and I could not implement it into my own.

Thanks in advance!

edit* forgot to add code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pylab
import os
import time
import datetime

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

def plot_data(i):

## Read data in ##
data = DataFrame(pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + '//Datasets//CexioCoinbaseKraken.csv'))

## Clean Timestamp ##
dates = list(data['Time'])
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') for date in dates]

## Parameter to show the previous 150 records of collected data ##
show_prices_index = len(dates)-150

## Define all variables to graph ##
dates = dates[show_prices_index:]
coinbase = list(data['Coinbase'])[show_prices_index:]
kraken = list(data['Kraken'])[show_prices_index:]
cexio = list(data['Cexio'])[show_prices_index:]
spread = list(data['max_spread'])[show_prices_index:]

## Clear both axis and update it with new data ##
ax1.clear()
ax1.set_title('Prices')
ax1.plot(dates,coinbase,dates,kraken,dates,cexio)
ax2.clear()
ax2.set_title('Spread')
ax2.plot(dates,spread)

## Runs plot_data function *interval* number of times ##
## Each interval, graph updates with new data ##

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_data, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include a code sample.

Comment: forgot to add that, it should be there now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is plt.text()

```
    plt.text(date_value, coinbase_value, 'the_text_you_want_here')
```

I put in date_value and coinbase_value, but you're going to want to store the last point in the line in question in a variable. You'll want to offset it by a certain amount - those are coordinates relative to your plot.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!